# Telerik theme is defeating right-alignment

Tags: winforms, telerik

I have a Windows form control that was built using Telerik RadTools for Windows Forms.  The form is styled nicely using the "Office 2010 Silver" theme.  However, at runtime, the theme seems to throw-off the alignment of some of my labels.

I have several rows of labels and textboxes on my form.  I want the labels' right sides to all line up.  This is easily done in the Visual Studio designer.  However, I believe my Telerik theme is throwing things off because it slightly changes the font, which alters the labels' sizes as well.  Since the designer only stores the x,y coordinates of my controls, the labels' right edges no longer line-up.

Is there a way to code around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by doing the following on all labels:

1. Set AutoSize to false.
2. Set x-location to that of the widest label.
3. Set size equal to that of the widest label.
4. Set TextAlignment to right.

Since all labels will have the same width and the same starting (left) location, their positions will now be fixed.  Setting the alignment to the right takes care of the problem.